# find: missing argument to `-exec' in perl script

Tags: perl, shell, sed, replace

I know there have been a lot of questions similar to my small problem. A few got fixed by a second -exec, but that's not what i need. Maybe i'm just not seeing where my problem really is...

I want to anonymize all IPs in the html-files in my weblog analytics output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use readPathsFromConf;

system ("find $readPathsFromConf::WWWPATH$readPathsFromConf::WWWSUBDIR -type f -name \"\*\" -exec sed -i '' 's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/anonymisiert/g' \{\} \;");
```

i only get

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I get the right files on STDOUT when i type this on the commandline:

```
find /var/www/statistics/ -type f -name "*"
```

but as soon as i add the exec-part i get the error.

Is something wrong with the Escape Characters?
What am i missing?
(Please excuse my English)

Comment: In this context, if you must do the `find` like that, use single quotes around the `*`.  Also consider splitting up the command into command and arguments in an array (`my @cmd = ( "find", "/var/www/statistics/", "-type", "-f", "-name", "*", "-exec", ...);`) and then using `system @cmd;`.  This avoids running a shell to run the command.

Comment: Why put * into single quotes instead of double quotes? Shell doesn't expand the globs in either of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape quotes and backslashes embedded in the string:

```
system ("find /var/www/statistics/ -type f -name \"*\" -exec sed -i 's/\\([0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\.\\)\\{3\\}[0-9]\\{1,3\\}/anonymousIP/g' {} \\;");
```

Also, note that on some platforms (e.g. Mac OS X) sed's `-i` option requires an argument - backup file extension.

Comment: `GNU sed` does not need an argument with `-i` option but I agree, I had the hardest time with my `mac` as it never allowed me to use `-i` option without a backup argument.

Comment: My implementation of sed is happy with -i without an argument (creates no backup). If I want to supply an argument, it cannot be separated by space from the `-i`. Version: GNU sed 4.1.5

Comment: Thanks, guys. I tried it out on a mac as well. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: You're welcome. The default version of `sed` on mac is the `BSD` one which isn't that feature rich. I downloaded `GNU sed 4.2` and it is much more flexible. If you want to download the `GNU version` then download it from [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/sed/) and build it with `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/bin
make
sudo make install`. You will need developers tools as we need `make` which doesn't come with `mac` either. Once downloaded you can rename your old `sed` to `_sed`. I got two - `[jaypal:~/Temp] which _sed
/usr/bin/_sed
[jaypal:~/Temp] which sed
/usr/local/bin/sed`

Comment: The backslashes were already meant to escape the corresponding following character - i think i should not escape them again

Comment: BUT i was wrong - thats exactly why it wasn't working - SOLVED Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would be easier and so much simpler just to leave the command as-is and change the quotation characters, e.g. `system(qq(find ... whatever));`

Comment: @Sorpigal This wouldn't work. Inside `qq()` one needs to escape backslashes as well. One could use `q()` if no variable interpolation is needed, though.

Answer (score 3):

Perl has a perfectly good [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/lib/File/Find.pm) core module.  There is no need to invoke an external utility to use **find**.

There is even a helper script called **find2perl** which might help you bridge from using the shell's find to Perl's.  This is discussed in the link above.

Comment: Yeah, i will try that too. I think i use system,exec or qx much too often where a perl-module should be used. But i am still rather new to Programming and Perl - i will get to this... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Because in:

```
system ("find /var/www/statistics/ -type f -name "*" -exec sed -i 's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/anonymousIP/g' {} \;");
```

The double quotes around the asterisk aren't escaped.  So, the interpreter thinks you're multiplying two things, and will automatically convert each of the strings to `0` (incidentally, this is also why you don't use `==` for string comparisons in Perl).

For example, the one-liner

```
perl -e 'use strict;use warnings;my $a="abc";my $b="def";my $c=$a*$b;print "$c\n";'
```

produces the output

```
Argument "def" isn't numeric in multiplication (*) at -e line 1.
Argument "abc" isn't numeric in multiplication (*) at -e line 1.
0
```

Since you have `strict` and `warnings` enabled, you too should have seen analogous warnings to those given above.

More importantly, however: if your script consists of a `system` call, why not just run the argument to `system` directly on the command line?

Comment: I am sorry - i posted an older version: i already found out about escaping the asterisk. I use a perl script to get my variables for the path - i already interpolated them for my post to keep it simple.

I corrected it in my post.

Comment: Okay, in that case, just escape the double quotes around the asterisk (or replace them with single quotes), and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

system ("find /var/www/statistics/ -type f -name \"*\" -exec sed -i 's/\\([0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\.\\)\\{3\\}[0-9]\\{1,3\\}/anonymousIP/g' {} +");
```

Comment: I think you need to escape backslashes as well.

Comment: The backslashes were already meant to escape the corresponding following character - i think i should not escape them again

Comment: No @AdamZalcman is right, you will need to escape them again.

Comment: BUT i was wrong - thats exactly why it wasn't working - SOLVED - Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Jaypal, i gave the "green hook" to Adam - is that ok for you?